# Compiling maven project

Tags: java, deployment, build, maven-2, wildfly

I have a maven project that am working on,I have ensured there are no errors and when I try to compile and deploy using this command "mvn clean compile package wildfly:deploy" it does not do anything and the blinking cursor just stays there. while my other projects the command works. What might be the problem? Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try running each goal separately and see what happens. 
Maybe your pom corrupted

Answer (score 1):

You need not to mention 'clean and compile' maven life cycle phases as invoking package will invoke these by default(no harm calling them as well).OR even package isn't required as wildfly:deploy will invoke package prior to executing itself.

Also please check if you have specified projcet configuration properly as-

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2.Final</version>
<configuration>
    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
</configuration>
```

Now at first make sure that you are in the same directory where your pom.xml is placed and issue: mvn wildfly:deploy